# NKLibrary wont let me build iphone newsstand app

Tags: iphone, newsstand-kit

I'm trying to build a newsstand app, when I attempt to run I get this link error: 
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NKLibrary", referenced from:

I thought the problem might be with my deployment target which is 4.0, but changing it to 5.0 did not help.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Voted for closure as it's very localised and an obvious mistake.

Comment: I faced the same issue with Baker-4.0. The project contained the reference to the framework in the Frameworks group but the framework itself was not added to the linked libraries. Misconfiguration, I know, but XCode did not indicate any sign of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve I had to add the newsstand framework to the frameworks

Comment: Well, if you don't add the framework, you can't use the framework.